# Format file size as MB, GB, etc

Tags: java, string, format, numbers

I need to display a file size as a *string* using sensible units.

For example,

```
1L ==> "1 B";
1024L ==> "1 KB";
2537253L ==> "2.3 MB"
```

etc.

I found [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801935/formatting-file-sizes-in-java-jstl), which I didn't find satisfactory.

I have come up with my own solution which has similar shortcomings:

```
private static final long K = 1024;
private static final long M = K * K;
private static final long G = M * K;
private static final long T = G * K;

public static String convertToStringRepresentation(final long value){
    final long[] dividers = new long[] { T, G, M, K, 1 };
    final String[] units = new String[] { "TB", "GB", "MB", "KB", "B" };
    if(value < 1)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid file size: " + value);
    String result = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < dividers.length; i++){
        final long divider = dividers[i];
        if(value >= divider){
            result = format(value, divider, units[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private static String format(final long value,
    final long divider,
    final String unit){
    final double result =
        divider > 1 ? (double) value / (double) divider : (double) value;
    return String.format("%.1f %s", Double.valueOf(result), unit);
}
```

The main problem is my limited knowledge of Decimalformat and / or String.format. I would like 1024L, 1025L, etc. to map to `1 KB` rather than `1.0 KB`.

So, two possibilities:

1. I would prefer a good out-of-the-box solution in a public library like [Apache Commons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Commons) or [Google Guava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava).
2. If there isn't, how can I get rid of the '.0' part (without resorting to string replacement and regex, I can do that myself)?

Comment: You might like [the answer here] [1] since it's a really efficient solution, and respects SI standards. [1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758606/how-to-convert-byte-size-into-human-readable-format-in-java

Comment: I am aware of that question (and of the accepted answer), I have also [posted an answer there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3758653/342852), referencing this question. This question came first, however, and didn't get that good an answer.

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice it was you who had posted the link to this question on that other one.  That's actually how I got here.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3758880/34088

Comment: I know. I would have accepted that one, had it been posted here.

Comment: If you change the last line to return NumberFormat.getFormat("#,##0.#").format(result) + " " + unit; it works in GWT too! Thanks for this, it's still not in Guava.

Comment: By ISO standard, kilo is expressed with a lowercase 'k'.

Comment: You might want to try the triava Open Source library. If you pass a proper DecimalFormat, you can get the desired "1 KB" output. Examples how to use it can be found in http://stackoverflow.com/a/38390338/1280825 and https://github.com/trivago/triava/blob/master/src/test/java/com/trivago/triava/util/UnitToolsTest.java .

Answer (score 402, accepted):

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public static String readableFileSize(long size) {
    if(size <= 0) return "0";
    final String[] units = new String[] { "B", "kB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB" };
    int digitGroups = (int) (Math.log10(size)/Math.log10(1024));
    return new DecimalFormat("#,##0.#").format(size/Math.pow(1024, digitGroups)) + " " + units[digitGroups];
}
```

This will work on all inputs (Long.MAX_VALUE is 8 EB), and the program is short!

Comment: This should be the "correct" answer as it takes the unit into account.

Comment: Agree, should be the correct answer. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758606/how-to-convert-byte-size-into-human-readable-format-in-java/3758880#3758880) for an even better output.

Comment: final String[] units = new String[] { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "EB" };
// now it works up to Long.MAX_VALUE!

Comment: To comply with international standards:

final String[] units = new String[] { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB" }; /* used with 1000 * /

final String[] units = new String[] { "Bi", "KiB", "MiB", "GiB", "TiB", "PiB", "EiB" }; /* used with 1024 */
See: http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/binary.html

Comment: and reverse function?...

Comment: nefo_x: The reverse function is impossible because you lose precision. If you wanted an approximation, you can parse the string to get the number part, then multiply that number by the factor which corresponds with the units string, i.e. "KB" would use the factor 1000.

Comment: A small comment: "kilo" is expressed with a lowercase 'k' and not an uppercase 'K'.

Comment: Might want to return "0 B" or otherwise include units in zero case.

Comment: Joe: Petabyte comes before Exabyte and don't forget these: Zettabyte, Yottabyte, so the complete list is: 
"B", "kB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB", "ZB", "YB"
See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yottabyte 
Yes I know ZB and YB are not needed today, but maybe in the future...;)

Comment: "This will work up to 1000 TB"  yes it is not working after this limit

Comment: Maybe using `.format(size/Math.pow(1024, Math.min(digitGroups, units.length)))` could fix the problem of filesizes above 1000TB?

Comment: Just a tip for Android developers : To show the file size in a nice readable way on Android, you can use `Formatter.formatShortFileSize(context,file.length())`

Comment: See scala solution ported from this code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609587/human-readable-size-units-file-sizes-for-scala-code-like-duration/40235429#40235429
Also support for ZB and YB.

Comment: Getting crash sometimes. Usually when its in KB
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1,010.3"
@WillemVanOnsem Can you please help me

Comment: This DecimalFormat will produce different results based on Locale. I added this to have consistency regardless of environment:
`DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US); 
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.##", symbols);`

Comment: Sadly, this won't work in conjunction with Linux `sort -h` like `du -h` output would. So back to the drawing board for me.

Comment: May print "1,002.3 kB". Probably better would be "0.9 Mb". Especially if 2-3 digits after period is allowed.

Answer (score 8):

You'll probably have more luck with `java.text.DecimalFormat`. This code should probably do it (just winging it though...)

`new DecimalFormat("#,##0.#").format(value) + " " + unit`

Comment: Does it work as required?

Comment: Strangely enough, after ten years, I haven't gone back and tested this. Try it yourself and see...

Answer (score 8):

It is surprising for me, but a loop-based algorithm is about 10% faster.

```
public static String toNumInUnits(long bytes) {
    if (bytes <= 1024)
        return String.format("%d B", bytes);
    int u = 0;
    for ( ; bytes > 1024*1024; bytes >>= 10) {
        u++;
    }
    return String.format("%.1f %cB", bytes/1024f, "kMGTPE".charAt(u));
}
```

Comment: Everything is loop based at the bottom.

Comment: @Evgeni Sergeev: What do you mean? Can you elaborate?

Comment: **Warning**: this doesn't work for bytes <= 1024 (result is always 0.0 B). You need to add `if (bytes <= 1024) { return String.format("%.1f B", (float) bytes); }` at the beginning of the method.