# Format file size as MB, GB etc the Microsoft way

Tags: string-formatting

Basically the same problem as [Format file size as MB, GB etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263892/format-file-size-as-mb-gb-etc): Format the size of a file in a human readable way. The twist: I need it to be the same algorithm that MS windows uses in its file explorer (or else my users get confused). What algorithm does MS use?

Note: It's not the one from the answers to the referenced question

Comment: Do you want the algorithm in Java (like the linked question) or are you just after pseudocode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fear I have found the answer: https://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/15/10140985.aspx