# Print integer with "most appropriate" kilo/mega/etc multiplier

Tags: algorithm, formatting, number-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert byte size into human readable format in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758606/how-to-convert-byte-size-into-human-readable-format-in-java)

Given an integer, I'd like to print it in a human-readable way using kilo, mega, giga etc. multipliers. How do I pick the "best" multiplier?

Here are some examples

```
        1 print as 1
    12345 print as 12.3k
987654321 print as 988M
```

Ideally the number of digits printed should be configurable, e.g. in the last example, 3 digits would lead to 988M, 2 digits would lead to 1.0G, 1 digit would lead to 1G, and 4 digits would lead to 987.7M.

Example: Apple uses an algorithm of this kind, I think, when OSX tells me how many more bytes have to be copied.

This will be for Java, but I'm more interested in the algorithm than the language.

Comment: I think you've got some solid unit tests in your question, all you need to do now is write the algorithm and test each case until they all validate. Only you know exactly what you want. Start with a couple until they validate, then move on doing one more each time.

Comment: I was hoping I didn't have to write it myself... I hardly think I'm the first one who ever wanted to have that algorithm...

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263892/format-file-size-as-mb-gb-etc). I think it does what you're after.

Comment: The answer is here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758606/how-to-convert-byte-size-into-human-readable-format-in-java/3758880#3758880

Answer (score 2):

As a starting point, you could use the Math.log() function to get the "magnitude" of your value, and then use some form of associative container for the suffix (k, M, G, etc).

var magnitude = Math.log(value) / Math.log(10);

Hope this helps somehow

Comment: Just noticed this answer using the log method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758606/how-to-convert-byte-size-into-human-readable-format-in-java/3758880#3758880

Comment: That's a good idea indeed.  Much like the dB (decibel) scale used to compare values with varying orders of magnitude.