# How to get the exact size of cache directory : android

Tags: android, caching

NEED: I simply trying to get occupied cache size of each application which is installed in my phone.

MY APPROACH:

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) 
{
    try 
    {
        Context mContext = createPackageContext(packageInfo.packageName, CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
        File cacheDirectory = mContext.getCacheDir();
        if(cacheDirectory==null)
        {
            cacheArrayList.add("0");
        }
        else
        {
            cacheArrayList.add(String.valueOf(cacheDirectory.length()/1024));
        }
    }
    catch (NameNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

RESULT: If directory is null it returning 0 (as condition). But if directory existing its returning 4 Kb always. I checked out cache of my apps by following the process:

Settings:->Apps:->ApplicationName

But I found its 0B there.

Why its happening can someone explain? and How do I get exact size of cache?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Calling length on a directory doesn't always return the correct size. You could try to iterate over the file list and add up all file sizes to get the total directory size.

Like this:

```
long size = 0;
File[] files = cacheDirectory.listFiles();
for (File f:files) {
    size = size+f.length();
}
```

Comment: Simplier: cacheDir.listFiles()?.sumOf { it.length() } ?: 0

Answer (score 19):

This has been more accurate to me:

```
private void initializeCache() {
    long size = 0;
    size += getDirSize(this.getCacheDir());
    size += getDirSize(this.getExternalCacheDir());
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourTextView)).setText(readableFileSize(size));
}

public long getDirSize(File dir){
    long size = 0;
    for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
        if (file != null && file.isDirectory()) {
            size += getDirSize(file);
        } else if (file != null && file.isFile()) {
            size += file.length();
        }
    }
    return size;
}

public static String readableFileSize(long size) {
    if (size <= 0) return "0 Bytes";
    final String[] units = new String[]{"Bytes", "kB", "MB", "GB", "TB"};
    int digitGroups = (int) (Math.log10(size) / Math.log10(1024));
    return new DecimalFormat("#,##0.#").format(size / Math.pow(1024, digitGroups)) + " " + units[digitGroups];
}
```

[Original post of the string to bytes formatting code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263892/format-file-size-as-mb-gb-etc)

Comment: This answer is more complete and more generic so it can be used anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

you will get cachesize from this function

```
  public void clearCache() {
   //clear memory cache

   long size = 0;
   cache.clear();

  //clear SD cache
   File[] files = cacheDir.listFiles();
    for (File f:files) {
      size = size+f.length();
     // f.delete();
  }
}
```