# Show total cache size in android

Tags: android, caching

I am developing an app, in which i need to display the total caches of all apps combined, in my **TextView**. how do i do that?

i have found this snippet [from an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206722/how-to-get-the-exact-size-of-cache-directory-android)

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> packages =  packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) 
{
try 
{
    Context mContext = createPackageContext(packageInfo.packageName, CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
    File cacheDirectory = mContext.getCacheDir();
    if(cacheDirectory==null)
    {
        cacheArrayList.add("0");
    }
    else
    {
        cacheArrayList.add(String.valueOf(cacheDirectory.length()/1024));
    }
}
catch (NameNotFoundException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Is it working or are you getting any error?

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar i dont know how to get it to work, i want to display my total cache in textview.

Comment: Fine. Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14507092/4596556) question and try to implement it.

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar the question in that link relates to **clearing all app caches**. my requirement is **displaying total app cache in textview** as said in the question.