# setting string in textview android

Tags: android, string, textview

this code is supposed to calculate total cache of all apps combined, but i am not able to test it. i want the calculated cache to be displayed in my textview, how do i do that?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myMethod();
}

private void myMethod() {
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    List<ApplicationInfo> packages = packageManager
            .getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

    for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
        try {
            Context mContext = createPackageContext(
                    packageInfo.packageName, CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
            File cacheDirectory = mContext.getCacheDir();
            if (cacheDirectory == null) {
                // cacheArrayList.add("0");
            } else {
                cacheArrayList
                        .add(String.valueOf(cacheDirectory.length() / 1024));
            }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cacheSize);
    myTextView.setText("YOUR STRING"); // replaces textview text
    myTextView.append("YOUR STRING"); // appends to current textview's text

}
```

---

Textview is as below

```
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/cacheSize"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:text="--" />
```

Comment: whats your problem?, are you not getting cache size? or you are not able to set the cache size on text view

Comment: i am not able to set the cache size on text view

Answer (score 1):

after for-each loop make another to put data from cacheArrayList to some string

```
for(String s : cacheArrayList){
    string = string+s+"\n"
}
```

and then put this string to textView

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to set the text on a TextView you are able to setText or appendText.

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cacheSize);
myTextView.setText("YOUR STRING"); // replaces textview text
myTextView.append("YOUR STRING"); // appends to current textview's text
```

Comment: The calculation of your total cache combined. Store it into a variable and replace "YOUR STRING" with your variable.

Comment: i am confused :( what is my variable? i got that code from an answer and it was incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

create a global variable

```
TextView txt_view;
```

inside oncreate method of the activity add,

```
txt_view = findViewById(R.id.cacheSize);
```

add this method in your activity

```
public void displaycache(){
                int k=0;
//on assuming cacheArrayList is a global variable
                for(int i =0;i<cacheArrayList.size();i++){
                   k+=Integer.parseInt(cacheArrayList.get(i));
                 }
                txt_view.setText(String.valueOf(k));
            }
```

call `displaycache();` after you call `mymethod();`

replace `myMethod()`

```
private void myMethod() {
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    List<ApplicationInfo> packages = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
        try {
            Context mContext = createPackageContext(
                    packageInfo.packageName, CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
            File cacheDirectory = mContext.getCacheDir();
            File[] files = cacheDirectory.listFiles();
            for (File f:files) {
                cacheArrayList.add(String.valueOf(f.length() / 1024));
            }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i got this incomplete code from some answer, what do i do about cacheArrayList?

Comment: here is the question and i am trying to calculate total cache and show it in my textview. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206722/how-to-get-the-exact-size-of-cache-directory-android

Comment: create global variable ArrayList<String> cacheArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: it is not working, it always shows the same value in my textview even if i clear cache , it shows "496"

Comment: in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206722/how-to-get-the-exact-size-of-cache-directory-android there is anwer selected as correct use that code to get the size, your current code calculates size of cache directory's name not size occupied by files in the directory

Comment: could you please tell me how do i put that snippet in my answer so that it calculates the correct cache size? thanks for the help!