# How to calculate cache size in android programmaticaly?

Tags: android, caching

> I am trying to calculate total cache size in MB in my app but its giving me Zero all time. Can anyone explain me.Please help me to calculate cache size.
>   below i have my code

```
 private void initializeCache() {
    long size = 0;
    size += getDirSize(this.getCacheDir());
    size += getDirSize(this.getExternalCacheDir());
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+size,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public long getDirSize(File dir){
    long size = 0;
    for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
        if (file != null && file.isDirectory()) {
            size += getDirSize(file);
        } else if (file != null && file.isFile()) {
            size += file.length();
        }
    }
    return size;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the exact size of cache directory : android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206722/how-to-get-the-exact-size-of-cache-directory-android)

Comment: but its not working for me

Comment: have u given permission that need?

Comment: no i did not give any permission

Answer (score 0):

Give this permissions in the AndroidMenifest.xml file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: still its giving zero in size

Comment: Is there any error showing? Try debug and check path of get chache DIR is correct ?

Comment: its not showing any error..i can't understand that path of get cache DIR

Comment: try this solution after give the permission, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206722/how-to-get-the-exact-size-of-cache-directory-android