# How to know file size from bytes

Tags: java

I have byte array, how to know file size ? (in JAVA)

```
File file = new File("patch");
file.length() // <--- it's good, but I haven't original file... (( I get file in bytes from DataBase !
```

Thanks

Comment: Get the byte array length...

Comment: for formatting, look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263892/format-file-size-as-mb-gb-etc

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have an array with you and every array has a length. That's it.

```
byteArray.length;
```

And

```
1kb = 1024 bytes
```

Comment: But I want to know size in Kb

Comment: You need formula to convert bytes to kilobytes ?  :)

Comment: @Vitaliy This is like "You gave me the mass in grams, but I need kg!"

Comment: Except 1kg = 1000g but in bytes it's actually 1kb = 1024b