# Define a function or a variable in scala that starts with a number

Tags: scala

Is it possible to write a `val` or a `def` that starts with a number? I know scala `val`s and `def`s can have pretty crazy characters in them. I'd like to make some constants like:

```
val 512MB = 536870912
```

But not sure if this is possible.

Comment: Not possible, but this is: `val _512MB = ...`

Answer (score 4):

You can use just about anything in a value name if you use backticks:

```
val `512MB` = 536870912
```

Answer (score 1):

As `@Jack Leow` mentioned, you can use any name with the backticks, but you'll have to use them all the time. Did you consider to use DSL in-place where you need these consts? In this case you can write something like this in your code:

```
val mySize = 512 MB
```

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609587/human-readable-size-units-file-sizes-for-scala-code-like-duration) thread for more details how you can achieve that.